# What components and IDE add-ins do you install with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-2010

After a clean install of Delphi, what components and IDE add-ins do you make certain that you install? What's your Delphi "rig"? Here's what I install after a clean installation:

1. Delphi 2007 / Delphi 2010
2. **[JCL / JVCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/)** - JEDI Code Library and JEDI Visual Code Library (600+ components)
3. **[JWA / JWSCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/files/)** - JEDI API Library & Security Code Library
4. **[GExperts](https://blog.dummzeuch.de/experimental-gexperts-version/)** - GExperts is a free set of tools built to increase the productivity of Delphi and C++Builder programmers by adding several features to the IDE. (Now includes the previously experimental code formatter.)
5. **[CnWizards](http://www.cnpack.org/showdetail.php?id=689&lang=en)** - Provides IDE enhancements to improve development efficiency
6. **[Virtual TreeView](http://www.delphi-gems.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=38)** - Virtual Treeview is a treeview control built from ground up. More than 5 years of development made it one of the most flexible and advanced tree controls available today.
7. **[MustangPeak Components](http://www.mustangpeak.net/)** (EasyList View, Virtual ShellTools, etc) - EasyListview is a control that has no dependance on the Microsoft Listview control but has all the features of the latest version from Microsoft. Also includes 'Explorer.exe' like shell components.
8. **[Synapse](http://www.synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php)** lightweight networking components - contains simple low level non-visual objects for easy programming without problems. (no required multi-threaded synchronization, no need for windows message processing,…) Great for command line utilities, visual projects, NT services
9. **[EurekaLog](http://www.eurekalog.com/index_delphi.php)** - EurekaLog is a complete bug resolution tool for Delphi and C++Builder  developers that gives your application the power to catch every exception and memory leak, directly on the end user PC, generating a detailed log of the call stack (with file, class, method and line number), optionally sending you a copy of each log entry via email or to a web bug-tracker.
10. **[DelphiSpeedUp](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=8)** - DelphiSpeedUp is an IDE plugin for Delphi and C++Builder. It improves the IDE’s startup speed and increases the general speed of the whole IDE.
11. **[DDevExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=10)** - DDevExtensions extends the Delphi/C++Builder IDE by adding some new productivity features.
12. **[IDE Fix Pack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=15)** - The IDE Fix Pack installs is a DLL-Expert that fixes the following RAD Studio 2007 bugs at runtime. All changes are done in memory. No file on disk is modified.
13. **[TPerlRegex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html)** - Regular Expression library for Delphi

How about other Delphi developers?

Comment: please add a short description - on what each component does

Comment: Eurekalog was supposed to catch bugs but it actually introduces huge amounts of bugs in your app (only take a look at how many bug fixes they have). It should be replaced by Madshi.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My list:

- The [Dev.Express Quantum grid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid/): **enhanced grid** component: once you get the hang of this component, you can use it in all sorts of scenarios (at least I have)
- [Dev.Express Quantum Tree list](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumTreeList/): if you know the grid component, you can use this component as well (**treelist and grid combined**)
- [Dev.Express Express bars](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExBars/): **menu bars and ribbons** (which I don't use myself) fully configurable by the user without any code from the developer - cool and usable even in previous Delphi versions
- [CNPack - Delphi IDE enhancer](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en): is a **Free IDE Plug-in Tool Set** for Delphi/C++ Builder/CodeGear RAD Studio to Improve Development Efficiency. One of the features (among tens of features) is a small form which attaches itself at the bottom left of any form you are designing, with buttons to left align, right align, center align etc ... your components on your form - check it out
- [HtmlViewer component](http://www.pbear.com/htmlviewers.html): as the name suggest: an **HTML viewing component** in native Delphi, now free, but I have been using it for a lot of years now. I have written almost all of my reports in my programs using html and css and the HtmlViewer component. It's amazing what you can do with html and css as a reporting solution (and it's standard too).

I have a lot of other components too, but these are the ones I use in every project (from small ones to the biggest I have written).

Comment: I remember having tried CNPack few years ago but it seemed very buggy, has this improved (for Delphi 2009 & 2010)?

Comment: I don't know about Delphi 2009 or 2010, I still use Delphi 7 for 95% of my Delphi development. But in D7, I haven't found problems (yet). Mind you, I don't use all possible features, so maybe there are bugs in the features I don't use. But for me, I wouldn't live without it. As with all such things: install it, try it and uninstall it if you don't like it.

Answer (score 9):

- [Bergsoft](http://bergsoft.net/) components. I Would be lost without [NextGrid](http://www.bergsoft.net/component/next-grid/overview.htm) and NextDBGrid (fastest **grid implementation** I came along)
- Lately, I'm seriously considering to start coding with a **Delphi framework**, [Delphi Spring Framework](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-spring-framework/) looks like a way to go.

*Delphi Spring Framework is an international open source project, whose mission is to provide a robust infrastructure framework that will help Delphi developers build solid, flexible and extensible enterprise applications and class libraries based on the Embarcadero® Delphi® 2010 for Win32 platform.*

Also it has a Dependency Injection container with 2 week build spawn

- [JEDI for Delphi](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/) with many wrappers for common dlls, also provides a robust VCL platform to develop

Answer (score 8):

I always install [TSmiley](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tsmiley/).  I can't get along without it.

Comment: Despite your witty attempt, I don't think many Delphi developers with real problems will find a Delphi R&D Manager recommending TSmiley very amusing.

Comment: @dmauric, I did. ;-)

Comment: Wow -- I'm really sorry that you didn't find that witty and amusing.  My bad.

Comment: @Dmauric.. Lighten up dude...

Answer (score 4):

JEDI API Library & Security Code Library for sure but probably my answer couldn't be more subjective since I participate in both projects ;-)
I find GExperts to be a must (can't live without it) and of course Virtual Treeview.

Answer (score 4):

The first tools I install are:

1. [Model Maker Code Explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html)
2. [GExperts](https://blog.dummzeuch.de/experimental-gexperts-version/)

Answer (score 4):

- **VirtualTreeView**  (Mike Lischke)
- **toolbar 2000** (Jordan Russel)
- **spTBXlib**  (Robert Lee) requires ToolBar 2000
- **DSPack** (Henry Gourvest aka progdigy) DirectX/DirectShow library
- **JCL + JVCL** (Jedi Project) made of every kind of stuff
- **Ararat Synapse** (Lukas Gebauer) Socket library (smtp, ftp, http,...)
- **SevenZip.pas** (Henry Gourvest) Wraps 7z.dll (The heart of 7-zip)
- **DragDrop Components** (Angus Johnson & Anders Melander)
- **ATBinHex** (Alexey Torgashin) file viewer with multiple mode (text, binary, hex, unicode, utf, Unicode Hex)
- **FastMM** (Pierre le Riche) memory manager
- **GraphicEx** (Mike Lischke) image library capable to open an impressive list of format, unfortunally, the dev seems to be stopped
- **Graphics32** (creator Alex A. Denisov. Now a team is involved) fast 32-bit graphics handling

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of [LockBox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tplockbox/) cryptography library

Answer (score 3):

the [ExpressQuantumGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid/) Suite from DevExpress - there cxGrid is incredible

Comment: PivotGrid is even better. I was amazed when I first tried it.

Answer (score 3):

**IDE Experts:**

1. ModelMaker Code Explorer
2. GExperts
3. [Castalia](http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/) Only for the Structural Highlighting.

**Components:**

1. DevExpress VCL Suite
2. DevRace IBDac
3. RemObjects AnyDac

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of [Async Professional](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpaproclx/) - a comprehensive communications toolkit for Delphi,

Answer (score 2):

**Components:**

1. [JCL & JVCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/files/JVCL%203/JVCL%203.39/JVCL339CompleteJCL211-Build3536.zip/download)
2. [EhLib](http://www.ehlib.com)
3. [FastReport](http://www.fastreport.com)
4. [Devart UniDAC](http://www.devart.com/unidac/)
5. [RemObjects DataAbstract](http://www.remobjects.com)
6. [RegExpStudio](http://anso.virtualave.net/)
7. [TMS Components Pack](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmspack.asp)
8. [EmbeddedWeb](http://www.bsalsa.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=35)

**IDE Experts:**

1. [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en)
2. [DDevExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=10)
3. [IDE Fix Pack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=15)

Answer (score 2):

- DevExpress
- RemObjects
- TMS Smooth Controls
- CnPack (just editor syntax highlighter)
- TPerlRegex
- TRichView
- VirtualTreeView
- FastMM FullDebug Mode (add to path)

Answer (score 2):

**Components**

1. DevExpress
2. FastReports
3. Raize
4. Zeos

**Ide Experts**

1. Gexperts

Answer (score 1):

- Remobjects:
  http://www.remobjects.com While
  definitely not free (beer), it's
  worth having.
- TPerlRegEx as you mentioned above
- XDBGrid. If anyone has alternatives for this one please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

1. [NativeXML](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html) - Fast, lightweight (and now open source) XML library
2. DevExpress Quantum Pack (Grid/Tree/Bars)
3. EurekaLog
4. GExperts
5. EmbeddedWB (bsalsa.com), enhanced embedded web browser control

Answer (score 1):

I think this is going to end up showing the biases of the kinds of development some people do.  :-)

**IDE Addins/Experts or External Tools**

- [Castalia](http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/)
- [GExperts](https://blog.dummzeuch.de/experimental-gexperts-version/)
- [DelphiSpeedUp](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=8) (for <= 2007)
- [DDevExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=10)
- [IDE FixPack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=246)
- [AsmProfiler](http://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/)

**Components**

- [VCL FixPack / AsyncCalls / RtlVCLOptimize](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=22) (Version appropriate)
- [NextGrid](http://www.bergsoft.net/)
- [DeHL](http://code.google.com/p/delphilhlplib/) (A set of generics-based collections and routines.  Very powerful.)
- [eDocEngine](http://www.gnostice.com/edocengine_vcl.asp) (Mostly for exporting Rave reports to various formats, but does more.)
- JCL & JVCL
- Synapse
- [TPerlRegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html)
- [XLSReadWriteII](http://www.axolot.com/components/xlsrwii20.htm)
- VirtualTreeView

There's some other projects I've been watching and tend to take a shot at using when the time is right:

- [hcOPF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/larryhengensopf/) [Homepage](http://www.tpersistent.com/)
- [ICS (Internet Component Suite)](http://www.overbyte.be/)
- [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/)
- [Delphi Spring Framework](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-spring-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

- [MadExcept](http://madshi.net/) because either that or EurekaLog tell you what actually went wrong.
- [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/index.htm) for making thread queues and pools much, much easier to manage.
- [GExperts](https://blog.dummzeuch.de/experimental-gexperts-version/)

Plus whatever else appeals to me on the day. I do a lot of contracting so it's more a matter of "what does the client already use" than "what do I prefer". But those three are the core things I'll try to drag onto any site with me just in the interest of sanity. I'd list fastMM but it's built in these days.